# Haskell Pattern Matching Optimization

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, pattern-matching

I've started learning Haskell for a university course, and I've written a function with pattern matching (Called `Simplify`). But I am a bit unsure how I can optimize my code, since I feel like it's a bit too hard coded.

Anyway, this is the code I've written:

```
data Proposition = Proposition Bool
                | Const Bool
                | Var String
                | And Proposition Proposition
                | Or Proposition Proposition
                | Not Proposition deriving (Show, Eq)


simplify :: Proposition -> Proposition

simplify (And _ (Const False)) = (Const False)
simplify (And (Const False) _) = (Const False)
simplify (And p (Const True)) = simplify p
simplify (And (Const True) p) = simplify p
simplify (Or _ (Const True)) = (Const True)
simplify (Or (Const True) _) = (Const True)
simplify (Or a b) = simplify (Or (simplify a) (simplify b))
simplify (Const b) = (Const b)
simplify (Var v) = (Var v)
simplify (Not (Const True)) = (Const False)
simplify (Not (Const False)) = (Const True)
simplify (Not p) = simplify (Not (simplify p))
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The closest you came was "I am a bit unsure how I can optimize my code".  Do you want to make it faster?  If so we'd need a benchmark.  Do you want less boilerplate?  A lambda case would help some for cheap.  Do you want style pointers? Hlint can tell you about things like those unneeded parenthesis.  Perhaps you mean something else by "optimize", let us know.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson It needs to be a bit faster as well as be less boiler plate.

Comment: There's an infinite loop with `simplify (Or (Var "x") (Var "y"))`

Comment: It looks like the `Proposition` data constructor might be there by mistake. You never mention it in `simplify` and it smells like a duplicate of `Const`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you generally want to follow the pattern

1. Simplify all sub-expressions.
2. Simplify the expression.

To me, this suggests the `recursion-schemes` package.

```
{-# language TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, DeriveTraversable #-}
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH

data Proposition
  = Const Bool
  | Var String
  | And Proposition Proposition
  | Or Proposition Proposition
  | Not Proposition
  deriving (Show, Eq)

makeBaseFunctor ''Proposition
```

This magically generates a type

```
data PropositionF x
  = ConstF Bool
  | VarF String
  | AndF x x
  | OrF x x
  | NotF x
  deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

along with some related instances. Note that `PropositionF` replaces each occurrence of `Proposition` with a copy of its type parameter. Now you can write

```
simplify :: Proposition -> Proposition
simplify = cata go
  where
    go :: PropositionF Proposition -> Proposition

    go (AndF (Const True) x) = x
    go (AndF f@(Const False) _) = f
    go (AndF x (Const True)) = x
    go (AndF _ f@(Const False)) = f

    go (OrF t@(Const True) _) = t
    go (OrF (Const False) x) = x
    go (OrF _ t@(Const True)) = t
    go (OrF x (Const False)) = x

    go (NotF (Const x)) = Const (not x)

    go x = embed x -- Catch-all: no rules apply
```

All the recursive simplification is handled "automatically", and all the "nothing exciting here" cases are handled in one line.